# SFML event::TextEntered not working properly

Tags: c++, events, text, sfml, keyevent

I'm making a school project about image modifying and I'm using sfml to make something like a console but a bit more "beautiful".

```
while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {

            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
        {
            //display text on screen
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when i press a certain key shortly on the display it appears like I've hold the key for a long period of time...

Example: pressing G, expecting to see only 1 G on the screen but on the screens there appears like 20 G.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` belongs inside the event polling loop:

```
while (window.isOpen()) 
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) 
    {

        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();

        if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
        {
           //display text on screen
        }
    }
}
```

From your description, there is probably more going wrong, but you need to post more code to see that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when pressing a key that signal is always transmitted, so
try this :

```
sf::RenderWindow window(...);
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
while(...)
{
    stuff...
}
```